# Audio stops working after playing several different files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, cordova-plugins, apk-expansion-files

I have written my own cordova plugin that handles loading media from expansion files. I have also built in my own basic support for playing audio, but I'm having some issues when playing multiple audio files after a few minutes.

What happens is the first 10-20 audio files will play without problems, but then it just stops playing without any noticeable errors. If I wait a few minutes the sometimes the audio will return. That makes me think I'm not disposing of things properly.

**Project File:** https://github.com/mcfarljw/cordova-plugin-expansion/blob/master/src/android/Expansion.java

Here is the snippet where I interact with the media player:

```
@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer media) {
        media.start();
    }

    public void pauseMedia() {
        if (media != null && media.isPlaying())
            media.pause();
    }

    public void playMedia(String filename) throws IOException {
        if (!this.isPlaying()) {
            Log.e("EXPANSION", "Media is currently playing!");
        }
        if (expansionFile == null) {
            Log.e("EXPANSION", "Expansion file not found!");
        }
        AssetFileDescriptor file = expansionFile
                .getAssetFileDescriptor(filename);
        if (file == null) {
            Log.e("EXPANSION", "Filename '" + filename + "' not found!");
        }
        if (media != null) {
            media.stop();
            media.release();
        }
        media = new MediaPlayer();
        media.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(),
                file.getLength());
        media.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        media.prepareAsync();
    }

    public void stopMedia() {
        if (media != null && media.isPlaying()) {
            media.release();
            media.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: does logcat sais something?

Comment: Nothing of interest popped out at me, but I'll have a closer look. Just wondering if anyone seeing anything I'm obviously doing wrong when handling the media player that could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I release after success and failure. Here's the basic code. In your case, add success and error handlers as follows.  I don't understand why you would call stop() during playMedia() but only if the user clicks stop.

```
     media = new Media(url,
     function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); 
     if (media != null) media.release(); },
     function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); 
     if (media != null) media.release(); }
     );

     media.play();
```